# How to concatenate two elements in pyspark RDD?

Tags: pyspark

I am newbie to Spark, asking a basic silly question. My data is in the format of

```
[firstName1,lastName1,firstName2,lastName2,firstName3,lastName3,.....,firstNameN,lastNameN]
```

so I have to iterate to this RDD. I have to concatenate firstName and lastName and produce an output like

```
[firstName1 lastName1,firstName2 lastName2,firstName3 lastName3,.....,firstNameN lastNameN].
```

By applying action `collect()` on the RDD and writing python code I am able to achieve it. But as this is a huge I can't apply collect. Somehow I am not able to understand how to achieve this.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
names = ["firstName1", "lastName1", "firstName2", "lastName2"]
rdd = sc.parallelize(names,len(names)/2)
rdd.glom().map(lambda row: [row[0]+" "+row[1]]).collect()
```

Output: `[['firstName1 lastName1'], ['firstName2 lastName2']]`

Comment: Thanks for reply Joss.. but my rdd is not like that it is what I have mentioned above. So how to convert from [firstName1,lastName1,firstName2,lastName2,firstName3,lastName3,.....,firstNameN,lastNameN] 
 to [["firstName1","lastName1"],["firstName2","lastName2"]]. That is the problem I have

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Then just change this:

`rdd = sc.parallelize(names,len(names)/2)
rdd.glom().map(lambda row: [row[0]+" "+row[1]]).collect()`. I have edited my answer too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joss for the replay. but lets say if i want to output ['firstName1 lastName1', 'lastName1 firstName2', 'firstName2 lastName2','lastName2 firstName3'] like so in this scenario how to iterate and concatenate to previous one. how to achieve in pyspark with using collect(). Is it supported? if so, could you please throw some pointers/suggestions/ references are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a hack or a quick workaround:

Case 1:

```
arr = ["firstName1", "lastName1", "firstName2", "lastName2", "firstName3", "lastName3"]

rdd_names = sc.parallelize(arr, len(arr)/2)
rdd_names.glom().map(lambda row: row[0]+" "+row[1]).collect()
```

The output would be:

```
['firstName1 lastName1', 'firstName2 lastName2', 'firstName3 lastName3']
```

`sc.parallelize(arr, len(arr)/2)` distributes the Python List into an RDD & `len(arr)/2` is the Number of Slices. I have chosen 2 here since you wanted to combine `firstName1 & lastName1`. You could change this to say 3, if you also had a `middleName1`.

`glom`  coalesces all elements within each partition into a list & `map-lambda` is self-defined.

---

Case 2:

Define the Lists

```
arr_1 = ["firstName1", "lastName1", "firstName2", "lastName2", "firstName3", "lastName3"]
arr_2 = arr_1[1:] + arr_1[:1]
```

Create RDDs

```
rdd_1 = sc.parallelize(arr_1)
rdd_2 = sc.parallelize(arr_2)
```

Zip & Map-Lambda

```
rdd_1.zip(rdd_2).map(lambda row: row[0]+" "+row[1]).collect()
```

The output would be:

```
['firstName1 lastName1', 'lastName1 firstName2','firstName2 lastName2',     
'lastName2 firstName3', 'firstName3 lastName3', 'lastName3 firstName1']
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay Kartik. but lets say if i want to output ['firstName1 lastName1', 'lastName1 firstName2', 'firstName2 lastName2','lastName2 firstName3'] like so in this scenario how to iterate and concatenate to previous one. how to achieve in pyspark with using collect(). Is it supported? if so, could you please throw some pointers/suggestions/ references are much appreciated.

Comment: @krishna I have updated my answer with the output you had asked. Hope that answers your question. Please update the question as well, for the benefit of others in the community.